# Как разбить строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Есть переменная со значением 0.65(156)

Необходимо вычленить следующее:

```
0  
65    
156
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы бы лучше почитали про регулярные выражения. Оно здесь самое простейшее. Пополнили бы свои знания довольно полезной вещью.

```
my $str = '0.65(156)';

my @str_parts = $str =~ /(\d+?)\.(\d+?)\((\d+?)\)/;
//массив @str_parts содержит три элемента. 0,65,156.
print $str_parts[0]; //0
print $str_parts[1]; //65
print $str_parts[2]; //156
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$w = 0.567;
@w = split (//, $w);
foreach (@w) {
     if ($_ =~ /\./) {
        next
     }
     print $_,"\n"
}
```

Comment: @Asid, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Никогда не получалось ладом форматировать код. Не фига не могу понять,как и где это делать, и где такая кнопочка "{}" находится.... Я пишу в geany, потом просто копирую и вставляю в ответ. Кто скажет толком что не так? А то вечно абра-кадабра выходит

Comment: Нашел такую кнопку пардон, и редактор отыскался. Как нить попробую ладом все. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -E 'my $n = "0.65(156)"; my @r = split /[\.\(\)]/, $n; say join(" ", @r)'
0 65 156
```